# Elastic search highlighter and Word delimiter compatibility

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I am facing a strange issue with the combination of using word delimiter and highlighter.

I have a String field named **model_name** which is analyzed at the **field level** using **word delimiter tokenizer** at both index and search time.
I have 2 other field named **style_name**, **vin_no**.

**Sample Data**

```
> model_name : Silverado 2500HD 
> Style : Sedan 4 dr vin_no :
> JTHKD5BH4F2236174
```

When i search my mapping with the vin no "JTHKD5BH4F2236174", it matches the record as expected but while highlighting it highlights Style along with vin_no. In the style field it matches the character 4.

I know word delimiter splits the number and characters respectively but since i have it as a field level analyzer wont that be applied only to the model_name field, how is elastic search really highlighting the style field

Comment: No, not asking about whether it's indexed. Is it stored (`"store": true`)?

Comment: No i dont have that, can you give some information on what it does?